# Bash: need to strip single quotes around a string

Tags: bash

Following is the code snippet from my bash script:

```
....
....
for ((i=0; i<${#abc[@]}; i++))
  do
    xyz=${abc[i]}
....
....
```

When the value of 'xyz' is substituted in the script, the value has single quotes around it:

```
'"6b76cdae-a4a8-4e88-989d-1581ae2d5b98"'
```

Why are the single quotes added and how do I strip them?

Thanks!

Comment: >>"Why are the single quotes added": Because your array `abc` had them as part of the string.

Comment: This question is lacking essential details.  Please show the starting value for `abc` (run `declare -p abc`).  Also, what statements did you run that led you to the conclusion that `bash` added single-quotes?

Comment: Another way that did the job for me is: `xyz=$($pqr | sed 's/\"//g')`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can replace

> xyz=${abc[i]}

with

> eval xyz=${abc[i]}

And here is an illustrating example what happens:

```
$ foo="'"'"bar"'"'"
$ echo $foo
'"bar"'
$ eval foo=$foo
$ echo $foo
"bar"
$ eval foo=$foo
$ echo $foo
bar
```

So, what happens with the holy `eval` is that the assignment gets split into two parts:

1. Evaluate `$abc`
2. Assign to `$xyz`

instead of just Step 2.

Maybe in your case you should consider to already change the assignment of `abc` but i don't know because of ignorance ;)

Comment: You sir just saved me a lot of time. Thank you

Answer (score 12):

You can try to remove **all** single quotes in array abc with Parameter Expansion:

```
abc=(${abc[@]//\'/})
```

You can try to remove **all** single quotes in string xyz with Parameter Expansion:

```
xyz=${xyz//\'/}
```

Comment: It still fails. I'll post the code snippet following the code mentioned in the query with 'set -x' enabled, in the following comment.

Comment: `#pqr=${xyz//\'/}

#test-rpc -a txt -s 1.1.1.1 $pqr networking.details | awk {'print $2'}

#test-rpc -a txt -s 1.1.1.1 '"6b76cdae-a4a8-4e88-989d-1581ae2d5b98"' networking.details | awk {'print $2'}`

Answer (score 0):

This is less elegant than some of the solutions provided, but you can use escaped octal in a pinch. This sort of trick can be used in a lot of weird edge cases. ASCII Octal for the single quote is `\047`. So this allows you to use `tr` to do the deed...

If `$MyVar` contains `'Some cool string I want dequoted'` then...

```bash
$ echo $MyVar
'Some cool string I want dequoted'

$ echo $MyVar | tr -d '\047'
Some cool string I want dequoted
```

Another example when you want to add single quotes:

`test.txt` contains:
111
222
333

```bash
$ awk '{print "\047"$1"\047"; print $1}' test.txt
'111'
111
'222'
222
'333'
333
```

Hope this is useful.